# How to count all lines, words, and characters in a file

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to write a program that counts all of the lines, words, and characters in a .txt file. I have the lines coming out but I don't know how to do the words or characters.

```
"""Write a function stats() that takes one input argument: the name of a text ﬁle. 
   The function should print, on the screen, the number of lines, words, 
   and characters in the ﬁle; your function should open the ﬁle only once. 
   stats( 'example.txt') line count: 3 word count: 20 character count: 98"""

def stats(inF):

    inFile=open(inF,'r')  
    text=inFile.readlines() 
    textLen=len(text)  
    print(textLen) 

    wordCount=0
    charCount=0

    for word in inFile.read().split():
        if word in inFile:
            wordCount = + 1
        else:
            wordCount = 1
    print(wordCount)

print(stats("n.txt"))
```

Comment: What have you tried? What do you think you should try? We can't just post the solution to your homework for you.

Comment: You're already doing words -- or something close to words.  For characters, simply take a running sum of the line lengths -- at the same place you count the lines.

Comment: It's not homework I'm preparing for an exam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reccomend using `with` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)) whenever you do file I/O in python. Also, iterate over each line instead of using `inFile.read()`. If you have a large file, your machines memory will thank you.

```
def stats(inF):

    num_lines = 0
    num_words = 0
    num_chars = 0

    with open(inF, 'r') as input_file:
        for line in input_file:
            num_lines += 1
            line_words = line.split()
            num_words += len(line_words)
            for word in line_words:
                num_chars += len(word)

    print  'line count: %i, word count: %i, character count: %i' % (num_lines, num_words, num_chars)


stats('test.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll point you in the right direction, not the best python coder but this is how you want to solve it logically.  Also this is considering you don't want to count " " or  "." as characters.

```
inFile=open(inF,'r')  

for line in inFiler:
    linecount++

    #use a tokenizer to find words
    newWord = true
    for character in line:

        #something like this
        if newWord:
            if character is not listOfNoneValidCharacters(" ", ".", ...etc):
                newWord = false
                charCount += 1
                wordCount += 1

        if not newWord:
            if character is not listOfNoneValidCharacters:
                charCount += 1
            newWord = true
```